# Postfix で受信したメールが Dovecot POP3 で参照できない

Tags: postfix, ldap, dovecot

Dovecot + Postfix + OpenLDAPの環境で、受信メールの件数を確認しようとしています。
コマンドより `mail`コマンドでメールの送信をおこないました。

```
[root@mailcli-01 openldap]# mail hoge13@mailsvr-01.local
Subject: testtesttest
testtesttesttest
.
EOT
```

そして、`/var/vmail/hoge13/Maildir/new` に移動して、受信メールがあることを確認しました。

```
[root@mailsvr-01 new]# ll
合計 4
-rw------- 1 mailadmin mailadmin 748  1月  6 14:27 2016 1452058078.Vfd00Ic36f3M146124.mailsvr-01.local
```

その上で、`telnet`コマンドで POP3 (110ポート) を指定してメールの件数を確認しましたが、0件と表示されてしまいます。

```
[root@mailsvr-01 new]# telnet mailsvr-01.local 110
Trying 192.168.100.41...
Connected to mailsvr-01.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK Dovecot ready.
USER hoge13
+OK
PASS naisyo
+OK Logged in.
LIST
+OK 0 messages:
```

どこを見直せばよいかご教授いただけますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: dovecotの設定ですが mail_location はどんな値になってますか？

Comment: @take88さん
ありがとうございます。
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildirとなってます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

メールボックスのパス名から推測すると、MDA (Mail Delivery Agent。メールボックスへメールメッセージを配送するサービス) として Postfix の `virtual`(8) を利用していると見受けられます。以下、その前提で。

Postfix `virtual`(8) に設定したメールボックスの場所と、MRA (Mail Retrieval Agent。メーラーに対してメールボックスへのアクセスを提供するサービス) である Dovecot POP3 サーバーに設定したメールボックスの場所が食い違っているためだと思われます。

Dovecot でユーザーのメールボックス形式や場所を調べるには `doveadm`(1) を利用します。これで設定を確認しましょう。以下は実行例です。

```
# doveadm user foobar
field   value
user    foobar
uid     8
gid     12
home    /var/mail/example.ac.jp/foobar
mail    maildir:~/Maildir
quota_rule      *:bytes=0M
```

以下のいずれかの対処が必要です。

- Postfix の設定を変更し、MDA として Dovecot の `lmtp` (LMTP サービス) あるいは `dovecot-lda`(1) を利用するようにする。(これにより、Dovecot で設定したメールボックスにメールメッセージが配送されるようになる)
- Dovecot の設定を変更し、メールボックスの場所を Postfix の `virtual`(8) に設定した場所に合わせる。

個人的には、前者の「MDA として Dovecot を利用する」ほうがお勧めです。こちらであれば、Postfix 側にメールボックスの場所を設定する必要がありませんし、Dovecot MDA 独自の機能 (quota, sieve など) を利用できるからです。

---

Postfix で Dovecot LMTP を利用する手順は Wiki に記載があります。

- HowTo/PostfixDovecotLMTP - Dovecot Wiki

  - http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixDovecotLMTP

---

以下は Dovecot + LDAP において、ユーザーのメールボックスに関する設定を行なう一例です。ご参考までに。(`dovecot.conf` や相当するファイルの設定と組合せる構成もありますが、それには触れません)

Dovecot のユーザーの各種属性を LDAP サーバーのユーザーエントリあるいは `dovecot-ldap.conf.ext` (あるいは相当するファイル) で設定しているのであれば、そのファイル中の `user_attrs` パラメーターを適宜調整する必要があります。もし `userdb { driver=prefetch }` を利用しているなら `pass_attrs` パラメーターも要調整。

例えば、すべてのユーザーの UID と GID が `mailadmin`、ユーザーエントリの `uid` 属性がユーザー名を保持している、メールボックスは maildir 形式で場所が `/var/vmail/<uid属性の値>/Maildir` であるなら、次のような記述になります。これはあくまで例ですので、ほかにも LDAP ユーザーエントリの属性 → Dovecot ユーザーの属性にマッピングしたい値があるなら、適宜調整してください。

```
user_attrs = \
  =uid=mailadmin, \
  =gid=mailadmin, \
  uid=mail=maildir:/var/vmail/%$/Maildir
```

詳細は Dovecot の Wiki をどうぞ。このあたり↓かな?

- AuthDatabase/LDAP/Userdb - Dovecot Wiki

  - http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/LDAP/Userdb

UID / GID の値(数値)によっては、`dovecot.conf` で `first_valid_uid`、 `last_valid_uid`、 `first_valid_gid`、 `last_valid_gid` パラメーターの値を調整する必要があるかもしれません。適宜調整してください。Dovecot の全ユーザーの UID / GID の名前がどちらも `mailadmin` で、その UID 値 / GID 値がどちらも `1000` の場合:

```
first_valid_uid = 1000
last_valid_uid = 1000
first_valid_gid = 1000
last_valid_gid = 1000
```

Comment: @fumiyasさん
ご丁寧に回答ありがとうございました！postfixのメールボックス指定とdovecotのメールボックス指定の場所がたしかに食い違っており、dovecotの10-auth.confの設定を見直したらうまく受信が表示できるようになりました。
userdb {
  driver = static
  args = uid=1000 gid=1000 home=/var/vmail/%u/Maildir
}
ありがとうございます。